# Neo4j: Display all connected nodes and their parent in tree-like graph

Tags: neo4j

got following layout in my neo4j db:

```
    a         
  / | \
 b  c  d     
/ \    |
e  f   g     
   |  / \
   h  i  j
```

What I'd like to do is to query for all child nodes e.g. if the start node is   **b**, then the children are **e,f,h**. All nodes have the same label (name) and the same relationship type.

I can accomplish this by:

```
MATCH (n:node {name:'b'}), (a)-[:DEPENDS_ON*]->(n) RETURN DISTINCT a.name as name
```

The problem is, that I'd like to have a "parent" for each child. e.g:

I want to know that **h** is in the output because it has parent **f**, **f** is there because the parent is **b** and so on.

Thanks a lot!

Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a query that returns all the distinct parent/child pairs.

```
MATCH path=(n:node {name:'b'})<-[:DEPENDS_ON*]-()
WITH NODES(path) AS np
WITH REDUCE(s=[], i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(np)-2, 1) | s + {p:np[i], c:np[i+1]}) AS cpairs
UNWIND cpairs AS pairs
WITH DISTINCT pairs AS ps
RETURN ps.p, "parent of", ps.c;
```

Comment: Hi Cybersam, Your code does exactly what I wanted it to do :) so many thanks for it! ( can't upvote, no rep. for it ). To be honest I don't understand it fully, so going to search in the documentation.
One question: what about performance when I'd have 1000+ nodes in the graph ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to operate on the paths rather than the nodes, trying something like this:

```
match (n:node {name:'b'}), p=(a)-[:DEPENDS_ON*]->(n)
WITH nodes(p) as pathNodes, length(nodes(p)) as l 
RETURN pathNodes[l-1] as c1, "parent of", pathNodes[l-2] as c2;
```

This will take any path and report that the next to last node in the path is the parent of the last node in the path.

Comment: Don't know if you have a syntax error in it but it complains that n is not defined,
`n not defined (line 3, column 8)
"RETURN n[l-1] as c1, "parent of", n[l-2] as c2;"
        ^

Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax`

But it doesn't make any sense for me (unless the syntax is wrong) because if I only try to `match (n:node {name:'b'}) return n` then it works.
Any ideas ?

Comment: It's still not doing what I want :) your code just seems to stop on the first "child nodes" (in my example illustration,when I match "a" your code just outputs a,b,c,d) but should output all of the nodes, when "a" is specified (matched)

Comment: Just to be more clear: If I match "a": in the beginning I'd like to have:
b - parent a, e - parent b, f - parent b,  h - parent f,
c - parent a,
d - parent a, g - parent d, i - parent g, j - parent g,

If I match e.g. "d": 
g - parent d, i - parent g, j - parent g.

The next important thing is that I never know how many child nodes there are / how deep is the graph, so it must not be a static query (or the numbers in it)

Comment: then just use `FOREACH` to go through each item in the `pathNodes` return collection, and you can do that.

Comment: Hi,thanks for advice, but I'm not that familiar with `FOREACH`. Would you please edit your original code to show me how to do it ? :) 
Thanks.
Peter

Comment: Hi, I'm still struggling to find a solution. Unfortunately `FOREACH` is not very well documented. Normally I would expect to use `RETURN` in `FOREACH` but this is not possible in cypher from what I know.