# Neo4j/Cypher display labels (match path)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

one of my questions was already answered:

[Neo4j: Display all connected nodes and their parent in tree-like graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721936/neo4j-display-all-connected-nodes-and-their-parent-in-tree-like-graph)

The final query was :

```
query = CypherQuery(graph, "MATCH path=(n {name:{node}})<-[:DEPENDS_ON*]-() WITH NODES(path) AS np WITH REDUCE(s=[], i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(np)-2, 1) | s + {p:np[i], c:np[i+1]}) AS cpairs UNWIND cpairs AS pairs WITH DISTINCT pairs AS ps RETURN ps.p, ps.c")
```

I need to be able to `RETURN` a label for each ps.p and ps.c in the same query. I've tried few things withot success. Please advise.

Thanks.

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to just amend `, labels(ps.p), labels(ps.c)` at the end (aka in `RETURN`)?

Comment: Hi, thanks, this works. I feel ashamed, as I'm sure I've tried it before posting this question here (maybe  I did some stupid mistake somewhere :( ). Anyway thanks again !