# Neo4j-Cypher Warning: The provided property key is not in the database but the variable is being declared above

Tags: neo4j, cypher, binary-tree

I really liked the example and the code of this link [Neo4j: Display all connected nodes and their parent in tree-like graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721936/neo4j-display-all-connected-nodes-and-their-parent-in-tree-like-graph/41909030#41909030)
but the thing is that as I  managed it to my database it thrown me some warnings.

> This feature is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
>
> Using 'length' on anything that is not a path is deprecated, please use 'size' instead

```
WITH REDUCE(s=[], i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(np)-2, 1) | s + {p:np[i], c:np[i+1]}) AS cpairs
                                        ^
```

> The provided property key is not in the database
>
> One of the property names in your query is not available in the database, make sure you didn't misspell it or that the label is available when you run this statement in your application (the missing property name is is: p)

```
RETURN ps.p, "parent of", ps.c;
           ^
```

> The provided property key is not in the database
>
> One of the property names in your query is not available in the database, make sure you didn't misspell it or that the label is available when you run this statement in your application (the missing property name is is: c)

```
RETURN ps.p, "parent of", ps.c;
                              ^
```

I fixed the first one by substituting the length with size...
What about the rest? since they're declared in previous lines?

Here's my version of code:

```
MATCH path=(n:Atomo {name:'Dema'})<-[:DAD_OF*]-()
WITH NODES(path) AS np
WITH REDUCE(s=[], i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(np)-2, 1) | s + {p:np[i], c:np[i+1]}) AS cpairs
UNWIND cpairs AS pairs
WITH DISTINCT pairs AS ps
RETURN ps.p, "parent of", ps.c;
```

Comment: Your query runs without errors in Neo4j 3.1.1. Which version are you using?

Comment: Basically i want to test in neo4j before i add to my code. 
I'm running the latest one neo4j on ubuntu

Comment: Can you share your example dataset? I created a small example graph: `CREATE (n1:Atomo {name:'Dema'})<-[:DAD_OF]-(n2:Atomo {name:'E'})<-[:DAD_OF]-(n3:Atomo {name:'F'})` - and the query returned the parent-child pairs without error.

Comment: Can you please edit this table into the question? Indent it as a code block - use 4 spaces or `Ctrl`+`K`.

Comment: you mean to share the code of the structure of database 
like { "_fieldLookup": {
        "n": 0  }  },
    { "keys": [ "n" ],
      "length": 1,
      "_fields": [ {"identity": {"low": 1,   "high": 0 }, "labels": [ "Atomo" ],
          "properties": { "name": "Tof"}, "id": "1"}],
      "_fieldLookup": {"n": 0 } }, {"keys": [ "n"], "length": 1,"_fields": [{"identity": { "low": 2, "high": 0 },"labels": ["Atomo" ],"properties": {"name": "Elen" }, "id": "2"} ],  "_fieldLookup": { "n": 0 } },

Comment: You can edit your original question - this allows you to insert the code in a more readable form.

Comment: CREATE (i:Atomo { name:"Dema"}), (t:Atomo {name:"Tof"}), (e:Atomo {name:"Elen"}), (m:Atomo {name:"Maroul"}), (n:Atomo { name:"Natal"}), (p:Atomo {name:"Pampo"}), (x:Atomo {name:"Xris"}), (xs:Atomo {name:"Xristina})
For the relationships: MERGE (m:Atomo { name: 'Elen' })  merge (c:Atomo { name: 'Tof' }) merge (i:Atomo { name: 'Dema' }); 
match (m:Atomo {name: 'Elen' }) match (i:Atomo {name:'Dema'}) merge (m)-[:MOM_OF]->(i); match (d:Atomo {name: 'Tof' }) match (i:Atomo {name:'Dema'}) merge (d)-[:DAD_OF]->(i); and so for the rest, Dema&Natali parents of Xris and Pampo and Maroul of Xristina

Comment: Thanks for the Cypher query, I'll look into it in a minute. About the edit - under the tags (neo4j, cypher, binary-tree), there is an edit button which takes you to http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41909100/edit where you can add the dataset to your question.

Comment: Tof & Elen parents of Dem and Maroul
---------Dem & Natal of Xris
------------Maroul & Pampo of Xristina and El